# SSL certificate verify error: (25:path length constraint exceeded)

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, kong, openresty, ssl-client-authentication

I am using Kong API Gateway (built on top of nginx). 
I configured client certificate authentication in nginx.conf:

```
ssl on;   ssl_certificate ${{SSL_CERT}};   
ssl_certificate_key ${{SSL_CERT_KEY}};   
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;  
ssl_client_certificate ${{SSL_CLIENT_CA_CERT_CHAIN}};  
ssl_trusted_certificate ${{SSL_CLIENT_CA_CERT_CHAIN}};  
ssl_verify_client optional;   ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

I get the error below on making a request with client certs:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Connection: close Content-Length: 237
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 05:15:02
>   GMT Server: openresty/1.13.6.2
>
> 400 The SSL certificate error
>
> ## 400 Bad Request
>
> The
>   SSL certificate error
>
> ---
>
> openresty/1.13.6.2

Nginx error log has details below:

> 2019/08/07 05:15:02 [info] 2886#0: *86 client SSL certificate verify
>   error: (25:path length constraint exceeded) while reading client
>   request headers

I have been using the same setup with older version of kong(n nginx) and it used to work just fine. Any idea how do i go about fixing it.
Manually verifying the client cert with `openssl verify -CAfile {SSL_CLIENT_CA_CERT_CHAIN} {CLIENT_CERT}` returns OK status.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `ssl_verify_depth`?

Comment: @RichardSmith ya i tried that. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an a fix, I observed that the last version of nginx "working" without this error is **`nginx:1.10.3`**.